# Is there a way to set the total files in Keras Conv2D() function for audio data input matrices?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

How can I set the total number of Audio Files, I have the following dimensions -

1440 Audio Files Dataset each having a 2D Matrix of features of size (16 * 12), kindly explain in this case how am I suppose to declare the Conv2D layer?

I am looking for alternative methods similar to .flow_from_directory() from ImageDataGenerator in Keras but for audio data (2D Matrix) to send batch_size to the CNN.

My current approach is as follows -

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 50)

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (16, 12, 1), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (5, 5))) 
classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.summary()
```

But gives the following output -

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_33 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 12, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_23 (MaxPooling (None, 3, 2, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_16 (Flatten)         (None, 192)               0         
=================================================================
Total params: 320
Trainable params: 320
Non-trainable params: 0

Error when checking input: expected conv2d_33_input to have 4 dimensions, but got an array with shape (1368, 16, 12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Conv2D` expects 4 dimensions. In the case of an image this would be (batch_size, width, height, channels). For an RGB image channels would be 3. In your case you only have 1 "channel" but you still need a dimension for it. So it should work if you add this to the start of your code

```
print(x.shape) #(1368, 16, 12)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=3)
print(x.shape) #(1368, 16, 12, 1)
```

Comment: I added the line as suggested,                                                                                               ```X = np.load('X.npy')
y = np.load('y.npy')

X = X[:, :192]

X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], 16, 12))
y = np.reshape(y, (y.shape[0], 1, 8))

X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=3)
y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=3)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.05, random_state = 50)``` following error occured ```ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_20 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1368, 1, 8, 1)```

Comment: Did you add `expand_dims` to both `x` and `y`?  You should only need to add it to `x`

Comment: I tried this - ```X = np.load('X.npy')
y = np.load('y.npy')
print(X.shape)

X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=3)
print(X.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.05, random_state = 50)
print(X_train.shape)``` it changes the dimensions as follows and the output is - **(1440, 193)
(1440, 193, 1)
(1368, 193, 1)** and the error - ```ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_22_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1368, 193, 1)```

Comment: Do I need to split the 193 data points into a 2D array (like 1 * 193 dimensions) as the error states it requires input to have 4 dimensions?

Comment: Are you loading x in a different way from before? The original error message you got said that the shape of x is `(1368, 16, 12)` bu now when you print it, it is `(1440, 193)`. If you want to use `Conv2D` then the shape of x should be something like `(1368, 16, 12, 1)`. If you want to use `Conv1D` then the shape of x should be something like `(1368, 193, 1)`

Comment: Earlier I selected 192 columns from the total 193 columns of X and reshaped them into 16 * 12 2D Matrix and used 2D Convolution, can you kindly explain which convolution should I use and why. Is there any good resource to understand the same which I should refer.

Comment: Here's an article that takes 1D audio samples, converts them into a 2D spectrogram and then passes them through a 2D convolutional neural network https://medium.com/gradientcrescent/urban-sound-classification-using-convolutional-neural-networks-with-keras-theory-and-486e92785df4

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this using,

`X_train= X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 1, 193)`

thus creating a 2D array of dimensions 1*193 and this 2D array was created for all 1440 files, thus the effective dimensions are 1440 * 1* 193.

The (1, 1, 193) in the reshape command above effectively means a 2D array as a 3D array of width 1 is just a 2D array.

Similarly did for X_test and the y matrix was left unaltered as suggested.

[Read this article for more info](https://www.kaggle.com/vishwasgpai/guide-for-creating-cnn-model-using-csv-file)